# ArangoDB Foxx: require() returned undefined

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I created an ArangoDB Foxx service, and successfully mounted it on some route using Foxx CLI. My service has a dependency which uses `randombytes`. When I call the service it returns an error saying `randomBytes is not a function.

For testing purposes I have created another service and just returned `typeof require('randombytes')`. And it returned `undefined`.

During installation Foxx CLI didn't warn me anything.

Does anyone had such experience?

Answer (score 0):

First, have you defined your randombytes module in your package.json dependencies ?

```
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "randombytes": "2.1.0"
  }
}
```

Then what about

```js
let randombytes = require('randombytes');
console.log(randomBytes(16));
```

Actually I just tested ... and it returns "undefined" as well ... so not sure it's a valid module for arango.

It's better to use arango's crypto methods

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/appendix-java-script-modules-crypto.html#genrandomnumbers

Comment: Agreed - use provided means when possible to keep things tidy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Foxx will alert you to missing dependencies, but it is important to make sure they are included in your ZIP package before installing your service/app.

My project is organized like this:

```
MyProject
   |-- foxx
       |-- service1
       |-- service2
       ...
```

I have a `package.json` file in the root of the project, as well as in each of the "service" folders. My workflow (make) runs `npm install` inside each "service" folder before creating the ZIP archive.

Just make sure to include the `node_modules` folder and all should be happy.

Comment: But I also agree with @solisoft - use the in-built packages/features when possible!